# how to redirect (or rewrite url) shortened url to long (original) url in asp

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have created a functionality which shortens a long url into short one. same as bit.ly and google url shortener
Fo e.g.

it shortens https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/india/karnataka-election-results-2018-live-updates-missing-mlas-raise-concerns-in-congress-jds-camp-2568569.html

to http://hostname/snKcxi    (http://localhost:9909/snKcxi)

I have created one page namely http://localhost:9909/shrtn.aspx which should take url key value : snKcxi from http://localhost/snKcxi and then transfer control to original long url i.e. if i hit http://localhost:9909/snKcxi it should redirect to : https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/india/karnataka-election-results-2018-live-updates-missing-mlas-raise-concerns-in-congress-jds-camp-2568569.html

i have tried URL rewriting, something like :

```
<rewrite>
  <rules> 
    <!-- For URL redirect-->
    <rule name="redirectRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^http://localhost:9909/$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:9909/shrtn.aspx" redirectType="Found"/>
    </rule>
  </rules> 
</rewrite>
```

But it fails to do the respected functionality. when i hit http://localhost/snKcxi it goes to 404 error page!
Can anyone help me out? any suggestions or changes??

What i wanted to do is take key from short url (i will search for long url from database based on key)
And then transfer it to long url

Comment: Is your website hosted on port 80? if not you should add port number too.

Comment: Something like  http://localhost:xx/shrtn.aspx

Comment: yeah it's http://localhost:9909/

Comment: Can I add it as an answer below and you select it as the correct answer, please?

Comment: but you haven't provided any solution! -_-

Comment: Do you mean you still have the issue after adding the port number?

Comment: Here : http://localhost/snKcxi it does not have the port number so it is normal to go to a page not found page

Comment: port number was already there, i haven't included in my question. i have updated the question you can go through it

Comment: Can you please try this: <match url="^http://localhost:9909/[a-zA-Z]+$"/>

Comment: no that won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added following rule in web.config file & the problem is solved.

```
 <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/shrtn.aspx?id={R:0}"/>
```